# Dynamically load part of code split react bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack, internationalization

I'm working on large scale ReactJs application. This app will contain thousands of localized strings so i decided to use[webpack i18n plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/i18n-webpack-plugin)
 to generate n bundles everyone of them with one of the localizations baked in

But here is the problem. Im not able to determine users language until Login screen is shown they fill in login details, choose language in combobox and they press login button. So my question is if it is possible to

1. **Split react bundle into Login screen and everything else (I'm using react router with Routes and Private routes)**
2. **To load lets say bundle_en_US chunk after user presses "Login" button**

thanks in advance for any ideas

EDIT added routes.js

```
// @flow
import React from 'react'
import {Redirect , Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import type {Store} from '../types/TReduxVariables'

import LoginPage from '../scenes/loginPage/LoginPage';
import Page1 from '../Page1';
import Page2 from '../Page2';

const getRoutes = (store : Store) => {
    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            store.getState().isAuthed ? (
                    <Component {...props}/>
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to={{
                        pathname: '/login'
                    }}/>
                )
        )}/>
    )

    const divStyle = {
        height: '100%',
    };

    return (
            <div style={divStyle}>
                <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact={true} path="/" component={Page1} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/page1" component={Page1} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/page2" component={Page2} />

            </div>
    )
}

export default getRoutes;
```

Comment: Can you show your Routes

Comment: Post edited with routes.js file